# Authenticate Against Database with Phil Sturgeon’s Rest-Server

Tags: php, api, authentication, codeigniter, rest

I'm trying to modify Phil Sturgeon's rest-server to authenticate against ion-auth. I changed _check_login to:

```
private function _check_login($username = '', $password = NULL)
{
    if (empty($username))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->rest->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
    $sql = 'SELECT api_key FROM users WHERE email = ?';
    $query = $this->rest->db->query($sql, urldecode($username));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $user = $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // If actually NULL (not empty string) then do not check it
    if ($password !== NULL AND $user['api_key'] != $password)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //return TRUE;
    return $user['api_key'];
}
```

My first question is do I need to do:

```
$this->rest->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
```

It seems to me like $this->rest->db should already be accessible since it's set in the constructor however I get an error saying I'm trying to query on a non-object if I don't add the load->database() line in _check_login like above. NOTE: I removed the if statement in the constructor that only initializes the db connection if keys or logging are enabled so this shouldn't be the issue.

My second issue I think is a result of question 1. Anyhow, after making the changes to REST_Controller my models in my REST controllers no longer work. The error I'm getting is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: User::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 50

which appears to be occurring when I make a call to a method in one of my model's.

Hopefully that's enough info to help pinpoint the problem. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the db class is at $this->db. Have you tried that?

EDIT: ah it seems that $this->rest->db is also an alias for $this->db.